# Select moment to start fade in animation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I wrote a piece of code with jQuery to start a fade-in animation on some content I have on my new portfolio website. The code works and the animation appears. Just the moment the animation starts is unlogic. In my mobile version, the animation starts when I'm halfway in the `p` text.

Any options to manipulate this within this code to select a certain amount of pixels from the `innerHeight` before the animation starts? Let's say when the `objectTop` reaches `windowMiddle`? Comments are much appreciated.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight();

    $(".fade").each(function() {
      var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object shows on scroll
        if ($(this).css("opacity") == 0) {
          $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
        // } else {
        //   object fade away scrolling up
        //   if ($(this).css("opacity")==1) {$(this).fadeTo(500,0);
        // }
      }
    });
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
.fade {opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fade">
  <p> Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/> </p>
</div>
<div class="fade">
  <p> Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/> </p>
</div>

<div class="fade">
  <p> Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/> </p>
</div>

<div class="fade">
  <p> Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/>Bladibladibla<br/> </p>
  <div>
```

Comment: Where is `.fade` class used in HTML?

Comment: Its there in the original code, thanks for the heads up I edited the post,

Comment: Please post a [mre]. I cannot see any fade in effect with your current example.

Comment: I've made an edit to your post to increase the size of the blah boxes and default to opacity = 0, so that the `if opacity==0` check does something - so we can see it "working".    It's a little unclear what the issue is.   They currently fade in when the *bottom* of the div is at the bottom of the window, so they appear to fade in when they're half-way up up the window.   Try changing to just `var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top` (and rename variable from "bottom" ofc) so they fade in as they appear.  Maybe `$(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHieght() / 4` ?

Comment: Thanks all I found my solution after going through the code again step by step. I will be more specific with any following question posted on stack. 

For my solution I had to remove `+ $(this).outerHieght() ` in 
`var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();` so we make it a top instead of a bottom and this effect is more accurate in the mobile version. 

Is it correct that we can also play with value's in the offset`()`? Lets say offset('50%') or how is this done correctly?